# Why the related Answer model doesn't get project_id?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the next models:

```
Project <(Many to Many)> Experiment (One to Many)> Question (One to Many)> Answer
```

When I try `Project::with('experiments.questions.answers')->find(1)`

as result, I get `answers` not only from `project` with `id: 1`, but from others too.

Structure `Answer` model:

```php
<?php

use App\Models\Answer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAnswersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('answer')->nullable();
            $table->integer('confidence_score')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->integer('state')->unsigned()->default(Answer::READY);
            $table->integer('element_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('question_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('answers', function ($table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['question_id']);
            $table->dropForeign(['project_id']);
        });

        Schema::drop('answers');
    }
}
```

If I add the next condition, it is work:
`Project::with(['experiments.questions.answers' => function($query) {$query->where('project_id', 1);}])->find(1)`

But how can I remove it from the code and to make it global?

Comment: Laravel relationships don't work like this, you have to manually specify special cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why this selection touch other projects, however, if you want to create a handy shortcut to fetch project with relations - create a method in a Model or your Repository:

```
public function findWithExperiments($id) {
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $project->load(['experiments.questions.answers' => function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }]);

    return $project;
}
```

Comment: I get it, that happens because an experiment can relate to the project with id 1 and project with id 2 at the same time. And when you grab this experiment you also grab second project questions and answers!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
Project::with('experiments.questions.answers')->find([1])
```